# Sorted(items, lambda) with multiple items, one reversed

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, lambda

How would I do the following sort?

```
import re
list_of_strings=['hulu_delta_20150528.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150524', 
                 'playstation_full_20150529', 'hulu_full_20150528.xml']
sorted(list_of_strings, key=lambda x: (
    x[:3], 
    re.search(r'\d{8}',x).group() if re.search(r'\d{8}',x) else None,
    -x # How would this be done as a third criteria?
))
```

Specially, how would I sort the item by reverse alphabetical as the third criteria? The end result should be:

```
['hulu_delta_20150524', 'hulu_full_20150528.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150528.xml', 'playstation_full_20150529']
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example. Give us a sample list `ftp.nlst()`, even if you just make stuff up.

Comment: Sort twice, second time with just `x` and `reverse=True`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary how would that be done?

Comment: @David542 Ignore the comment, posted an answer.

Comment: In the particular example you site - why would you want hulu_full to be second? It is not alphabetically second and date-wise second as well. So it's not very convincing what you want to do - unless you have a large example set and explain - collisions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compare the negative ordinal value of the items to compare them reverse alphabetically:

```
#  All hulu strings have same date 
>>> list_of_strings=['hulu_delta_20150528.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150524', 
                     'playstation_full_20150529', 'hulu_full_20150528.xml']
>>> files = sorted(list_of_strings, key=lambda x: (
    x[:3],
    re.search(r'\d{8}',x).group() if re.search(r'\d{8}', x) else None,
    [-ord(c) for c in x]
))
>>> files
['hulu_delta_20150524', 'hulu_full_20150528.xml', 'hulu_delta_20150528.xml', 'playstation_full_20150529']
```